# IronRouter : waiton display loading template but never render final template when subscriptions are ready

Tags: meteor, iron-router

i'm testing the last version of Iron Router V1. I'm in front a problem about the waitOn hook :
    loading template is displayed
    subscriptions are loaded (callback on subscription is well called)
    but the final template is not rendered

A console log message ask me if i have used this.next() in OnBeforeAction hook, that's all.

Here is the source code : https://github.com/Rebolon/meteor-tutorial-router
Here is the sample app : http://tuto-router.meteor.com/waiton

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation does not mention this.next() requirement for onRerun().

```
onRerun: function () {
  console.info('onRerun');
  this.next();
}
```

should do the job.